# Same segments in multiple .asm files and addressing modes

Tags: assembly, 8051

I have two questions.

I'm using Keil uVision (v. 5.14.2.1) and Nordic Semiconductors nRF24LE1 (8051 MCU)

**Question 1**

I have two source files. Main.asm and Functions.asm
I'm creating one code segment in Main.asm and want to place code written in Functions.asm in the same segment. Is it possible, and how do I do that? See example below of how I try to do it

Main.asm

```
; Main.asm

            extrn      code       (extFunc)

?PR?SEG?A   segment    code
?PR?SEG?B   segment    code

            rseg       ?PR?SEG?A
Main:
            MOV        A,    P0
            CPL        A
            MOV        P0,   A
            SJMP       Main

            rseg       ?PR?SEG?B
Something:
            ACALL      extFunc
```

Functions.asm

```
; Functions.asm

            public     extFunc

            rseg ?PR?SEG?B

extFunc:
            CLR        A
            RET
```

**Question 2**

See the code example below with comments

```
; Question 2
?PR?MYCODE  segment    code
?DA?MYDATA  segment    data

            rseg       ?DA?MYDATA
varA:
            ds         1

            rseg       ?PR?MYCODE
Main:
            MOV        varA,     #0x00    ; Line 1
            MOV        A,        varA     ; Line 2
            MOV        A,        #varA    ; Line 3
```

Is it correct that?

Line 1: Sets varA (where ever that is in memory) = 0x00?

Line 2: A = varA = 0x00?

Line 3: A = address of varA?

If Line 3 is not correct. How do I get the address of varA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer to Question 1, from Ax51 User's Guide:

*A segment is a block of code or data memory. A segment may be relocatable or absolute. A relocatable segment has a name, type, and other attributes. Segments with the same name, from different modules, are considered part of the same segment and are called partial segments. Several partial segments with the same name are combined into one segment by the Lx51 linker/locater. An absolute segment cannot be combined with other segments.*

Question 2: Line 3 stores the address of varA